# Ionic framework, how to deny to hide alertPopup by back button on the Android?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-alertdialog

on home page of my app is displayed Ionic alertPopup message during the first run.

User should not be able to hide this alertPopup by back button (he should always tap on the button).

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: title,
                template: message
            });
```

How can i do it please ?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in using

```
$ionicPlatform.offHardwareBackButton
```

and

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/%24ionicPlatform/